# pandas dataframe add multiple rows for group of values with apply

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a pandas dataframe contains the following columns:

```
sate_1      state_2 
-----       -----
New York    Washington
Ohio        Utah
```

what I want to do is to construct an input date for each distinct combination of state_1 and state_2 so the results would be:

```
sate_1       state_2          date_time
New York     Washington     2017-11-01 00:00
New York     Washington     2017-11-01 03:00
New York     Washington     2017-11-01 06:00
Ohio         Utah           2017-11-01 00:00
Ohio         Utah           2017-11-01 03:00
Ohio         Utah           2017-11-01 06:00
```

so basically for each distinct row I want to return 3 time periods starting from today,s date.
I have the logic to get the datetime but I'm doing this through a loop of all the records which is a time consuming since my data would contain more than 1M rows . I was wondering is there a way to do this using the apply function, which I'm assuming it will be much faster.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you need *all possible* combinations of `state_1` and `state_2`, or just three time periods for each of the rows in your input DataFrame? In other words, should your example output also contain `New York, Utah` and `Ohio, Washington`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Setup

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'state_1': ['New York', 'Ohio'],
                   'state_2': ['Washington', 'Utah']})
# df:
#       state_1     state_2
# 0     New York    Washington
# 1     Ohio        Utah
```

#### Add the first of three desired dates to each row

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime('2017-11-01')
# df:
#       state_1     state_2     date
# 0     New York    Washington      2017-11-01
# 1     Ohio        Utah            2017-11-01
```

#### For each row, create a new DataFrame with all three desired dates, broadcast state names across these dates, and concatenate the list of DataFrames into one

```
pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame(
        {'state_1': row.state_1,
         'state_2': row.state_2,
         'date': pd.date_range(row.date, freq='3h', periods=3)
        }
    ) for i, row in df.iterrows()
], ignore_index=True).loc[:, ['state_1', 'state_2', 'date']]
# df:
#   state_1     state_2     date
# 0 New York    Washington  2017-11-01 00:00:00
# 1 New York    Washington  2017-11-01 03:00:00
# 2 New York    Washington  2017-11-01 06:00:00
# 3 Ohio        Utah        2017-11-01 00:00:00
# 4 Ohio        Utah        2017-11-01 03:00:00
# 5 Ohio        Utah        2017-11-01 06:00:00
```

Comment: What would be the format for giving 15m intervals?

Comment: Hey @sheharbano, to get 15-minute intervals, replace `freq='3h'` with either `freq='15min'` or `freq='15T'`. For reference, the full list of so-called *date offset frequency strings* are listed on this huge documentation page (search for "available date offsets"): https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html

Comment: Great to hear @sheharbano!